# How to display alphabet as the first record in the table using orderBy in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi everyone i'm working on angularjs to display list of records in table . The difficulty i'm facing is to display the table in ascending order, i have used the alphabet record (X) which i need to display has the first record in the table.

Let me give you the html page.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="sort('bucket')" th-sort by="order">Bucket<span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='bucket' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='bucket' && reverse==false)"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('productCode')" th-sort by="order">Product Code<span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='productCode' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='productCode' && reverse==false)"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('countOfAllocatedAccount')" th-sort by="order">Allocated
                <span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='countOfAllocatedAccount' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='countOfAllocatedAccount' && reverse==false)"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('countOfCollectedAccount')" th-sort by="order">Collected
                <span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='countOfCollectedAccount' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='countOfCollectedAccount' && reverse==false)"></span></th>
            <th ng-click="sort('sumOfArrearsOfAllocatedAmount')" th-sort by="order">Total Allocated Amount
                <span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='sumOfArrearsOfAllocatedAmount' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='sumOfArrearsOfAllocatedAmount' && reverse==false)"></span>
            </th>
            <th ng-click="sort('sumOfCollectedAmount')" th-sort by="order">Total Collected Amount
                <span class="sortorder descending" ng-hide="(sortKey=='sumOfCollectedAmount' && reverse==true)"></span>
                <span class="sortorder" ng-hide="(sortKey=='sumOfCollectedAmount' && reverse==false)"></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in view_data">
            <td><span ng-hide="view_data[$index-1].bucket == item.bucket">{{item.bucket}}</span></td>
            <td>{{item.productCode}}</td>
            <td>{{item.countOfAllocatedAccount}}</td>
            <td>{{item.countOfCollectedAccount}}</td>
            <td><span>{{item.sumOfArrearsOfAllocatedAmount | currency:"&#8377;"}}</span></td>
            <td>{{item.sumOfCollectedAmount | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And let me show you the output :

[image]

And here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CvKNc/152/

As shown in the image the bucket value X is in the last value in the table. But, i need display it in the first row of the table and rest numbers should be set in the ascending order. I'm stuck here, Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: You are using symbol, numbers and letters in the same column. You should define your own ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//creating an application module
var myAppModule = angular.module("myApp", []);
myAppModule.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http,$filter){   

    var jsonData = [
                      {
                        "bucket": ">120",
                        "productCode": "SBML",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 640                      
                      },
                      {
                        "bucket": ">120",
                        "productCode": "SBHL",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 1391
                      },
                      {
                        "bucket": "1-30",
                        "productCode": "SBHL",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 1081
                      },
                      {
                        "bucket": "1-30",
                        "productCode": "SBML",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 408
                      },
                      {
                        "bucket": "1-30",
                        "productCode": "SBML",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 998
                      },                      

                      {
                        "bucket": "X",
                        "productCode": "SBML+",
                        "countOfAllocatedAccount": 93
                      }
                    ];
         
   $scope.products =  $filter('orderByValue')(jsonData);
  
    });//end controller



myAppModule.filter('orderByValue', function() {

  return function(items, field) {
     var filtered = [],filteredX = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
     if(item.bucket=="X")
        {
           filteredX.splice(0, 0, item);
        }else if(item.bucket.indexOf(">") !== -1) {
          filtered.push(item);
        }else
          {
           filteredX.push(item);
          }     
    });    
     angular.forEach(filtered, function(item) {
           filteredX.push(item);
        }); 
    return filteredX;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">       
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table border="1">
                <tr>

                      <th>Bucket</th>   
                      <th>PRODUCT_CODE</th>              
                      <th>Allocated #</th>                   
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in products  ">

                      <td ><span ng-show="products[$index-1].bucket != p.bucket">{{p.bucket}}</span></td>                                     
                      <td><span>{{p.productCode}}</span></td>
                      <td><span>{{p.countOfAllocatedAccount}}</span></td>                     
                </tr>               
            </table>
</div>
  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Pravin thanks for your reply with answer , its almost  correct  but i need to  set  the records in ascending  order .

Comment: @ Pravin X is now in the correct place , no prob in that . but i need to  set  the rest  of the numbers in ascending  order .

Comment: Please check updated it is fine or not because  now it is  X,1-30 ,>120 order

Comment: pleasure to help you @anil chean